# simple unix script to check a txt file and do another job

Tags: shell, unix

I have two bat scripts: A.bat and B.bat. A.bat generates a txt file (year.txt) that contains the last year of simulation, such as 2005.

I want the A.bat to check the year.txt every 30 seconds. If the year.txt shows 2005, then the A.bat will call the B.bat.

Please teach me how to do this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check every thirty seconds, simply use [`sleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep):

```
while true; do
    if test "$(cat year.txt)" = "2005"; then
        B.bat
    fi
    sleep 30
done
```